# How to use devise_token_auth gem for social login?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, devise

How do you implement an authentication system using OAUTH with the devise_token_auth gem?

I have searched pretty much everywhere on the internet, including all the documentation in https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth repo and searched in all it's issues.

I am developing an API to handle user SIGN UP and LOG IN through social networks but I can't find a way to make this work with this gem.

**PROBLEM**

```
  def social_login
    uri = URI('http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook')
    response = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
    puts response.body
    redirect_to :back
  end
```

this method for testing the API (localhost:3000) gives me this response:

```
<html><body>You are being <a href="http://localhost:3000/omniauth/facebook?resource_class=User">redirected</a>.</body></html>
```

My Facebook callback URL:

```
http://localhost:4000/auth/facebook/callback
```

Client tester: localhost:4000

My API routes:

```
                  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                             Controller#Action
        new_user_session GET    /auth/sign_in(.:format)                                 devise_token_auth/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /auth/sign_in(.:format)                                 devise_token_auth/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /auth/sign_out(.:format)                                devise_token_auth/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /auth/password(.:format)                                devise_token_auth/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /auth/password/new(.:format)                            devise_token_auth/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /auth/password/edit(.:format)                            devise_token_auth/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /auth/password(.:format)                                devise_token_auth/passwords#update
                         PUT    /auth/password(.:format)                                devise_token_auth/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /auth/cancel(.:format)                                  devise_token_auth/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /auth(.:format)                                         devise_token_auth/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /auth/sign_up(.:format)                                 devise_token_auth/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /auth/edit(.:format)                                    devise_token_auth/registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /auth(.:format)                                         devise_token_auth/registrations#update
                         PUT    /auth(.:format)                                         devise_token_auth/registrations#update
                         DELETE /auth(.:format)                                         devise_token_auth/registrations#destroy
     auth_validate_token GET    /auth/validate_token(.:format)                          devise_token_auth/token_validations#validate_token
            auth_failure GET    /auth/failure(.:format)                                 devise_token_auth/omniauth_callbacks#omniauth_failure
                         GET    /auth/:provider/callback(.:format)                      devise_token_auth/omniauth_callbacks#omniauth_success
                         GET    /omniauth/:provider/callback(.:format)                  devise_token_auth/omniauth_callbacks#redirect_callbacks
        omniauth_failure GET    /omniauth/failure(.:format)                             devise_token_auth/omniauth_callbacks#omniauth_failure
                         GET    /auth/:provider(.:format)                               redirect(301)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use Omniauth https://github.com/intridea/omniauth and make integration with devise_token_auth they've explained in the documentation https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth#omniauth-authentication

Comment: I did all that and still, there's a couple of errors, for example:

Routing Error :: No route matches [GET] “/omniauth/facebook” on the api